# .NET Core MVC with IdentityServer4 login not working

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a .NET Core MVC application ([bejebeje.admin](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Admin)). Its authorization and authentication are delegated to IdentityServer4 ([bejebeje.identity](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity)).

I have IdentityServer4 running in a docker container.

[image: docker ps]

When I try to login, nothing happens. I expect to be taken to an action on my .NET Core MVC application, but instead I get taken back to the login page even though the login details I input are 100% accurate.

Here is the [IdentityServer4 logs from the docker container](https://gist.github.com/JwanKhalaf/11876066af25f9fd9ef19b19bcaad9d1).

The IdentityServer4 configuration matches, here are the values from the IdentityServer4 side (from a `variables.env` file):

```
$ cat variables.env
Database__DefaultConnectionString=Server=database;Port=5432;Database=bejebeje_identity;User Id=postgres;Password=secure-pass;
InitialSeedConfiguration__Username=john.doe@outlook.com
InitialSeedConfiguration__Password=Password123!
InitialSeedConfiguration__FirstName=John
InitialSeedConfiguration__LastName=Doe
InitialSeedConfiguration__Email=john.doe@outlook.com
InitialSeedConfiguration__Website=https://www.john-doe.com
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__FrontendClientId=front-end-client-id
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__GoogleClientId=google-client-id
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__GoogleClientSecret=google-client-secret
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__FacebookClientId=fb-client-id
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__FacebookClientSecret=fb-client-secret
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__AdminClientId=bejebeje-admin-mvc-local
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__AdminClientSecret=secret
InitialIdentityServerConfiguration__AdminEndpoint=https://localhost:5021
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secure-pass
POSTGRES_DB=bejebeje_identity
```

And here is the .NET Core MVC side (from user secrets):

```
Sentry:SendDefaultPii = true
Sentry:MinimumEventLevel = Warning
Sentry:MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = Debug
Sentry:IncludeRequestPayload = true
Sentry:Dsn = <secret url>
Sentry:DiagnosticsLevel = Error
Sentry:Debug = true
Sentry:AttachStackTrace = true
IdentityServerConfiguration:ClientSecret = secret
IdentityServerConfiguration:ClientId = bejebeje-admin-mvc-local
IdentityServerConfiguration:Authority = http://localhost:5005
ConnectionString = Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=bejebeje;User Id=bejebeje_user;Password=admin;
```

What am I doing wrong? In the logs I see no problems! All messages in the log seem positive/Ok.

**UPDATE**

In IdentityServer4, in the Login ActionResult, I added a `Console.WriteLine()` like this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInResult result = await _signInManager
  .PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
  Console.WriteLine("User is logged in!");

  // rest of code ommitted
}
```

And ran the whole thing again. I then checked the logs, and I **can see that message in the logs** so the user details are correct! Yet I still face the same problem.

Comment: can you confirm if it works with locally hosted IDS4? I checked ur log, and all I found is `Showing login: User is not authenticated` - checking ur code now...

Comment: I create the user from the config in `variables.env` here: https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Identity/blob/8cbd4a19c1c0f0104ad1234b52effcec9954340c/Bejebeje.Identity/Services/DataSeederService.cs#L92 I find it very strange that it says the user is not authenticated!

Comment: I found no obvious issue in ur code too! Did you get a chance to confirm if its working locally(no container)?

Comment: I just tried running IdentityServer4 locally and manually went to `/account/login` and followed through the code by place a debug point on the login `POST` method. It does [sign me in](https://imgur.com/a/yAxL6a3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many days of struggling, I figured it out.

It was to do with `https`/`http`. Something called a same site cookie that Chrome had recently implemented to force everyone to move to `https`.

To overcome this, I just updated everything to use `https`, even inside **docker containers**. You need to copy the [self-signed certificates into the docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

I'm happy now.